# Derive terminal voltages for a BJT

Tags: bjt

**Question:** A BJT for which \$BV_{CBO}\$ is 30 V is connected as shown in the figure below. What voltages would you measure on the collector, base and emitter?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZLaHt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer: \$V_B = 13.3 V\$

\$V_C = 43.3 V\$

\$V_E = 12.6 V\$

I have no idea how to proceed with this question. How is the breakdown voltage related to the terminal voltages?

Comment: \$V_B\$ is for **B**ase, not breakdown.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am sorry?  I know \$V_B\$ is for the base.

Comment: Then what is this remark about breakdown in your question?

Comment: BV is for breakdown I believe.

Comment: I see, sorry, missed it. Probably it is relevant as this voltage is actually reached here looking at the answer.

Comment: Is it possible that your answer, \$V_\text{C}=43.3\:\text{V}\$, is wrong? In other words, could it be: \$V_\text{C}=33.3\:\text{V}\$ (or more exactly, \$V_\text{C}=33.35\:\text{V}\$)? (The other two make sense to me.)

Comment: @jonk It can be wrong. The question is from Sedra and Smith (6 Edition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something does not make sense in the supplied answer, 43.3V on the collector implies Ic = (50V - 43.3V)/10k = 0.67mA, but Ie is 1mA due to the current source, so by Kirchoff Ib must be 0.33mA, making the voltage across Rb 6.6V (With the base negative with respect to ground, not impossible with a magic current sink in the emitter, but still)....

Jonk has the right of it I think 33.3V Vc makes sense to me as well.

Here is how I would probably tackle this thing (But it has been a few years) 
:
Due to the 30V breakdown, Vb = Vc - 30V.

Then the collector current is the 1mA from the current source plus the current in the base pulldown resistor (Vc - 30V)/20k 
So Ic = 1mA + (Vc - 30V)/20k. From Kirchoffs laws concerning currents into and out of a junction.

But Vc can also be written in terms of the voltage drop across the collector load, Vc = 50V - 10k * Ic, so some substitution and trivial algebra should get you an answer.

Further due to the forward biased base-emitter diode we know that Ve = Vb - 0.7v.

That would be my take on it.

Comment: Yeah. This is where my own head was at, too. I simply performed a breakdown current estimate of \$\frac{50\:\text{V}-30\:\text{V}}{10\:\text{k}\Omega+20\:\text{k}\Omega}\approx 665\:\mu\text{A}\$. That, of course, must also be the base current. The rest just fell out from there.

Comment: @jonk That works, I was trying for a bit more of a teachable moment. I am never quite sure with these clearly academic questions quite what level to pitch the answer, is the rather handwavy thing sufficient or should I be citing my device physics shelf? Decisions, decisions...

Comment: That's why I didn't try writing an answer and instead asked a question about the problem. In order to pose the question itself, I didn't need to engage a "teachable moment." I only had to come up with a mental calculation to see if I could get the proposed answer. I couldn't, but did come up with something nearby. So I asked. You were faced with answering the question, so you had decisions to make. I had the easier problem of just trying to make sense in my own head; not having to explain my process. (To you, of course, that was trivial. All I had to do was give a nod to it.)